# MongoDB - Is it possible to when updating a value just count up 1 to the current value?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Is it possible to when updating a value just count up 1 to the current value? Probably it's possible to first read the value and then just add up 1 but isn't there another (more efficient) way? I'm using the pymongo connector.

Example record:
`{"productId": "125", "value": 5.99, "amount": 50}`

Code:

```py
searchQuery = {"productId": "125"}
newValues = { "$set": { "amount": +1 } } # Add 1 to the amount
mycol.update_one(searchQuery, newvalues)
```

Comment: Take a look at the [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way would just set amount to 1 every time regardless; what you need is:

```
mycol.update_one(searchQuery, { '$inc': { 'amount': 1 }})
```